# Can't implement GJK distance algorithm

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, collision-detection, game-engine

I'm trying to design my own physics engine from scratch, as well as the vector/matrix libraries.
Everything worked beautifully so far, until I tried to implement collision detection in my library. First with SAT, worked great for detecting, but I wanted to find the distance between the objects as well. Then I tried to implement the GJK distance algorithm, just to see if I can find the distance between the origin and a polygon. But it just doesn't work, the smallest distance perceived by the algorithm that I implemented was one of the vertex of the polygon:

[image: stack1.png]

I know I made the other libraries from scratch, but I'm positive that they are working. Anyways, here's the code where I've implemented the GJK:

```
    #objectL[0] is a hexagon
    v = objectL[0].nodes[0]
    W = []
    u = 0
    close_enough = False
    while not close_enough and v != Vector(0,0): 
        w = objectL[0].support(-v)  
        d = v*w/abs(v)  #*:dot product abs:magnitude
        u = max(u,d)
        close_enough = abs(v) - u <= 0.0001
        if not close_enough:
            W.append(w)
            while len(W)>2:
                del W[0]
            v = Vector(0,0).vectorToLine(*W) #distance from the origin to the simplex
                                             #formed by W
```

And now the support method:

```
    def support(self,axis):
    maxP = self.nodes[0]*axis  #dot product of first vertex with the axis
    n = self.nodes[0]
    for node in self.nodes[1:]:
        p = node*axis
        if p>maxP:
            maxP = p
            n = node
    return node
```

Those are the code snippets, that I think is where the error is, but I can't find it. The GJK algorithm I've copied from [here](http://www.dtecta.com/papers/jgt98convex.pdf). Thanks!

Edit:
[Here](http://www.filedropper.com/physics_2) is my project(implemented in pygame)

Comment: Interesting algorithm, never heard of it before, but seems extremely useful! Have you taken a look at [this](http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/04/gjk-distance-closest-points/) link? It looks like they implement the algorithm in code there for the distance portion, even though it isn't in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the error. Which wasn't on the implementation, but rather on the functions that I've previously made: the support, which returned `node` instead of `n` and the `vectorToLine` function which returned an incorrect vector(negative value).

Also for those that are reading this post years from now, and trying to implement this algorithm, please note that I only changed the `while len(W)>2` part to:

```
                while len(W)>2:
                maxD = 0
                for w in W:
                    if abs(w)>maxD:
                        maxD = w
                W.remove(maxD)
```

Which removes the farthest point of the simplex/triangle, so it gets the two closest point(to the origin) to continue the algorithm.